# What is the good practice for returning "large" class private member?

Tags: c++, return, private

```
typedef std::vector <std::vector <int>> DataType;

class MyClass
{
public:
    const DataType &getData() const;
    DataType getData2() const;

private:
    DataType data;
};

const DataType &MyClass::getData1() const
{
    return data;
}

DataType MyClass::getData2() const
{
    return data;
}
```

Should I avoid copying it by using getData1()? Is there any performance benefit to prefer const reference instead of getData2()? How should I return such "large" private member from class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in what the users can do with your `DataType`:

- with `getData1` they can call only member functions marked `const`, and access member variables as if they were declared constant, and only during the lifetime of the object that returned the reference.
- with `getData2` users can call any methods they wish, and make modifications as needed.

The price for using `getData2` is copying: if `DataType` has an expensive copy constructor, the calls may become significantly more expensive.

You could improve upon this by implementing a copy-on-write strategy, and sharing data with reference counting. Of course, users will be able to make copies manually by calling the copy constructor on the constant reference:

```
DataType dtCopy(obj.getData1());
```

Comment: The only answer here that goes beyond "hurr durr, avoid the copy". +1 (Although you should mention the issue of lifetime where returning a reference)

Comment: Users could always copy the result of getData1(), so getData2() does NOT (really) allow them to do more.

Answer (score 3):

In this example, it seems that the member `data` is actually part of the interface. It's not clear whether you intend the data to be mutable after the class has been created. If not, you can simply expose the const data member as 'data as interface' like this:

```
typedef std::vector <std::vector <int>> DataType;
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(DataType data_) 
    : data(std::move(data_))
    {
    }

    // data is interface, but it's immutable so perfectly safe
    const DataType data;
};
```

Which will be optimally efficient in all cases, plus it has the advantage of being automatically thread-safe.

If you intend that `data` is mutable then the normal thing to do is provide a const reference accessor plus a mutable reference accessor (although this is actually logically equivalent to simply exposing the data on the interface)

something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(DataType data) 
    : _data(std::move(data))
    {
    }

    // immutable access
    const DataType& data() const { return _data; }

    // mutable access
    DataType& data() { return _data; }

    // another option - allow the client to move the data out of me
    DataType&& steal_data() {
        return std::move(_data);
    }

private:    
    DataType _data;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Returning a large class private member is almost *never* a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Returning by const reference is preferable in this case as it would avoid unnecessary copying.

Comment: However if MyClass is deleted or goes out of scope you have an invalid reference - so depends on use  - Without other info I would set data to be a smart pointer and pass that out as then the live cycle will be managed automatically and you don't copy the large data

Comment: Ask yourself a question should that data be used outside the context of object for which it was initialized...

Comment: @Mark `const DataType& ref = getData1()` // the user knows it is a reference and should care about the scope - `DataType copy = getData1()` // the user request a copy

Answer (score 0):

You should use getData1() rather than getData2(). Copying is not needed there.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for prefer `getData1()` is because client can do `const DataType& data = myClass.getData1();`, which avoids copying the large data.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Generally it's better to return reference to a const object it you're not 100% sure your client will need a copy of a data. Even if your client does need a copy of data, they can call copy constructor on their side. So, `getData1()` allows some options. With `getData2()` you always have to deal with copy constructor.

```
const DataType & MyClass::getData1() const
{
    return data;
}
```

^ This will return a reference to a constant object. This is a way to go. Clearly, it wouldn't allow outside modification of the object.

```
DataType MyClass::getData2() const
{
    return data;
}
```

^ And this is not for "cool kids". This will call your huge object's copy constructor on `return data`.